# Display the biggest history possible with the fc command

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

For the moment, I use:

```
fc -l 1
```

Do you know a best way to use the fc command to display a longer history?
I already know that it's possible to increase the value of the variable HISTSIZE.

Comment: `$HISTSIZE` limits the size of the stored command history. It is not possible to get more than than the size of stored history. The history is stored in `$HISTFILE` (restricted by `$HISTSIZE`), what is not in it can't be found elsewhere.